# CreateMethodInfo : Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

Previously in a loop I had a working call to `CreateMethodInfo`, and the method signature had no parameters.

Now I've changed this (for performance reasons) so that the method in question has parameters, and it's failing with the following error message now:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\qz5wsaeb.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies.

I'm calling this:

```
var method = CreateMethodInfo(script, "Methods", "GetValue");
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { control });
```

The value of script:

```
public class Methods
{
    public static void GetValue(Control control)
    {
        // During runtime this part is dynamic and can change
        control.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 70);
        control.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(204, 107);
    }
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Basically I want to invoke the method and pass a parameter, in this case a Control.

### Edit

CreateMethodInfo:

```
public static MethodInfo CreateMethodInfo(string script, string className, string methodName)
{
    using (var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        var parms = new CompilerParameters
        {
           GenerateExecutable = false,
           GenerateInMemory = true,
           ReferencedAssemblies = { "System.Drawing.dll","System.Windows.Forms.dll" }
        };
        return compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, script)
            .CompiledAssembly.GetType(className)
            .GetMethod(methodName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `CreateMethodInfo`? - it doesn't appear to be an official framework method. Anyway, if all you did was literally to add the parameter, the most likely explanation is that the definition for `Control` can't be found. Perhaps you need to explicitly add an assembly reference before requesting the method reference.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the names of referenced assemblies to the CompilerParameters structure, as you are correctly doing, is not enough for the compiler to be able to resolve the reference to `Control` in

```
public static void GetValue(Control control)
```

You must either add the referenced assembly name with a `using` statement to the script, like this:

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class Methods
    {
        public static void GetValue(Control control)
        {
    ...
```

or else, if you prefer, qualify symbol references with the defining namespace:

```
    public class Methods
    {
        public static void GetValue(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
        {
    ...
```

Incidentally, you can troubleshoot this kind of issue yourself by inspecting the `Errors` property on the object that `CompileAssemblyFromSource` returns.